# Submitting a form by hitting return when the submit button is hidden; works in Firefox, does nothing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, google-chrome

I have a form with some input fields and a hidden submit button (hidden via style="display:none").

When you hit the return key when an input field is focused in Firefox, the form submits.

However in Chrome, when you hit return, nothing happens. I was wondering, how do you add this functionality back to Chrome?

Here's the form, take a look at it in Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/B59rV/2/

```
<form method="post"  action="/xxxx" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input type="hidden" value="SSjovFqEfRwz2vYDIsB6JRdtLAuXGmnT+tkyZnrtqEE=" name="authenticity_token">

    <div class="input text_field">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="user_session[email]" />
  </div>

  <div class="input text_field">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" size="30" name="user_session[password]" />
  </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" style="display: none;" >

</form>
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/B59rV/

Comment: Errrm... take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/B59rV/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have literally no idea why it's not working in Chrome. I think it's a bug.

However, *it is* somehow to do with that `display: none`.

I found a nasty, horrible (!!) workaround:

```
input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px
}
```

Don't hide it: instead, position it off the screen.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/TzY2F/) - works in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, I had that as a solution already, but I don't think I could sleep at night if it was implemented. Tell you what, if there are no more answers in a day, you can have the big green tick.

Comment: @Smickie: I'm going to retag the question with some higher exposure tags. I just noticed you have none of html/css/javascript.

Comment: What about another dirty "solution": `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: @Bazzz: I considered that, but it obviously leaves the space where the button would be: http://jsfiddle.net/TzY2F/1/

Comment: One could use `visibility:hidden;position:absolute`. The absolute positioning takes it out of the document flow and thus the space disappears. Using `visibility:hidden` seems better than `top:-1000px` though which always seems hacky!

Answer (score 3):

Tested in Chrome 22 and Firefox 18 perhaps this is the best workaround

```
.hide-submit {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

<button type="submit" class="hide-submit">Ok</button>
```

Or a more generic way

```
input[type=submit].hide,
button[type=submit].hide {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

<input type="submit" class="hide">Go</input>
```

This basically hides the element in plain sight, no need to push it outside the screen

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is:

```
<input type="submit" hidden />
```

Example:

```html
<form onSubmit="event.preventDefault(); alert('logging in!')">
  <label for="email">email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" required />

  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" required />

  <input type="submit" hidden />

  <p>Press enter to log in</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a security "feature", although I haven't found a definitive explanation yet. I tried http://jsfiddle.net/B59rV/2/ without the password field and the alert occurs as expected. Same thing happens in IE8 for what it's worth. Those are the only browsers I have on this machine, so haven't tested on any others.

Comment: The `display:none;` is precisely where the problem comes from on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround i found, at least as dirty as positioning it out of the screen, is `width:0; height:0;` : somehow, Chrome doesn't interpret it like a hidden element

Answer (score 0):

This is like Pioul's answer but I needed to do the following for a **input[type=file]** element:

```
position:absolute; //this helps the "hidden" element not disrupt the layout
width:0;
height:0;
// For <= IE7 a 1px piece of the form element still shows
// hide it with opacity=0; Tested element was input:file.
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
```

NOT tested with **input[type=text]**

Just another approach but I don't think this is much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: The opacity only virtually hides the button. It is still clickable. Bad solution.